# Failed to boot macbook from Ubuntu USB

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, operating-systems, disk-utility

I am trying to put Ubuntu on my aging Macbook, as my optical drive is dead, [I am following this guide to do so via USB.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick)

The process seems to go fine in the terminal, but when I boot I only get a single option from the operating system selector on boot, and when OsX restarts the USB disk is declares as 'not readable by this system'

*Details*

Machine : Macbook 21.Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo build 10K549
Os      : Snow Leopard 10.6.8

USB Drive is made using Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop i386